# Getting error while initializing string with string character array?

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to initialize this string s1 but Idk why I'm getting this error, This may be due to s[0] is character but why everything turns fine when I initialize and declare same string s1 but in diffrent lines, one after another.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

int main()
{
  std::string s = "text";
  std::string s1 = s[0];

  std::cout << s1;
}
```

Error:

```
 error: conversion from '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char>, char>::value_type' 
 {aka 'char'} to non-scalar type 'std::__cxx11::string' {aka 
 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>'} requested
 std::string s1 = s[0];
                    ^
```

This is working fine:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

int main()
{
  std::string s = "text";
  std::string s1;
  s1 = s[0];

  std::cout << s1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) for char. There's a  copy assignignment, which works for the second snippet.

However, you can write either like

```
std::string s1 ( 1, s[0] );
```

Comment: @Evg Opps sorry. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`std::string s1 = s[0];` is initialization, it doesn't work because `std::string` doesn't have [any constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) taking a single `char`.

`s1 = s[0];` is assignment, it works because `std::string` has a [`operator=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D) taking a single `char`.

Answer (score 1):

If we take a look at the documentation, we can see that

- `std::string` has no constructor that takes a `char` type - [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)
- It does have an overload for the `operator=` that can take a
  `char` - [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D#mw-content-text)

> [The copy assignment that takes a `char`] replaces the contents with
> character ch as if by assign(std::addressof(ch), 1)

As to why, consider the fact that the `std::string` already has so called **fill-constructor**, `string s(n, val)`, that takes an initial value `val` and fills the string with `n` copies of it. So there's no need to have special case for `n == 1`:

```
std::string s1 = "text";
std::string s2(1, s[0]); // One char of value s[0]
```

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  string s = "text";
  string s1;
  
    s1 = s;
  cout << s1;

}
```

> the code should work now.

Comment: What? This is not compilable.

Comment: why not compatible?? this is working absolutely fine for me.  check on any online compiler

Comment: @BIJAYGHOSH It doesn't https://godbolt.org/z/hxWWxWz64 .

Comment: @BIJAYGHOSH Now, your answer does something that's completely different from what OP is trying to do.